# Access override delete sticks on record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, delete-row

I'm using MSAcess 2013

I'm trying to override the Delete command for a datasheet form so instead of deleting the record in my table source it flips a bit field called *Retired* and then re-queries the table so retired records disappear.  The problem is that after highlighting a record and pressing the delete key, that record stays in the data-source until I click off the record.

Here's the code behind:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()

    If Me.Accepted <> 0 Then
        Me.Accepted = 0
    End If
    Me.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)

    Cancel = True

    If Me.Retired <> 1 Then
        Me.Retired = 1
    End If

    DoEvents
    'DoCmd.GoToRecord Record:=acNext

End Sub
```

Here's a pic of my datasheet after I pressed the delete key.  Notice how the little pencil is shown on the row selector.  That indicates the delete has been canceled and the bit has been flipped in the source, but the re-query won't process while the row is highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Have to get record out of edit mode. Save the record.

Comment: Is Retired a number type field?

Comment: @June7 - Retired is a number type because I noticed the Yes/No Boolean field had some odd behavior.  What would you use to save a record.  I'm seeing a Cmd call, that I can make, but docs on VBA are very terse.  Thanks

Comment: Looks like saving the record works, but causes the `Me.Requery` call to error

Comment: What error? Why is AfterUpdate triggered? It should not be triggered by programmatic edit of data. Why edit a field in AfterUpdate event? BeforeUpdate might be better.

Answer (score 1):

First, use the *BeforeUpdate* event:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate()

    If Me.Accepted <> 0 Then
        Me.Accepted = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Next, your problem is, that the Delete action is wrapped in a transaction. Thus, while this is active, no requery can take place, and the "deleted" record will stay visible.

I don't see an easy way around this, other than to cancel the delete event completely, and have a button to "delete" a record which actually gets updated.